Xcode Cloud Connection reset by peer
Iam when trying to build Kotlin Multiplatform project on Xcode cloud I get the following error

Showing All Messages
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':composeApp:iosArm64CompileKlibraries'.

   > Could not download lifecycle-runtime-iosArm64Main-2.9.0-alpha08.klib (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-iosarm64:2.9.0-alpha08)

      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime-iosarm64/2.9.0-alpha08/lifecycle-runtime-iosarm64-2.9.0-alpha08.klib'.

         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime-iosarm64/2.9.0-alpha08/lifecycle-runtime-iosarm64-2.9.0-alpha08.klib'.

            > Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration

               > Connection reset by peer

   > Could not download lifecycle-common-iosArm64Main-2.9.0-alpha08.klib (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-iosarm64:2.9.0-alpha08)

      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common-iosarm64/2.9.0-alpha08/lifecycle-common-iosarm64-2.9.0-alpha08.klib'.

         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common-iosarm64/2.9.0-alpha08/lifecycle-common-iosarm64-2.9.0-alpha08.klib'.

            > Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration

               > Connection reset by peer

   > Could not download lifecycle-viewmodel-iosArm64Main-2.9.0-alpha08.klib (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-iosarm64:2.9.0-alpha08)

      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel-iosarm64/2.9.0-alpha08/lifecycle-viewmodel-iosarm64-2.9.0-alpha08.klib'.

         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel-iosarm64/2.9.0-alpha08/lifecycle-viewmodel-iosarm64-2.9.0-alpha08.klib'.

            > Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration

               > Connection reset by peer


Any ideas what might be causing it? on my Mac it compiles without a problem and also those links work. Also tried to use different version of lifecycle lib, but then even more libs fail to download
